# How to share models in a multitenant enviroment with Mlflow?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, mlflow

The company I work for are using Databricks with Azure as a storage service. My group is trying to create a centralized model registry that allows us to push and pull models into different instances of Databricks. We are aware that we can share models within the same subscription (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/machine-learning/manage-model-lifecycle/multiple-workspaces) however we have multiple subscriptions so this wont work for us. From what I've read there are two solutions for this. Use Azure blob storage or an SQL solution. Unfortunately I cant find much info online. Anyone have any idea how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solutions is to copy MLflow objects (registered models, experiments and runs) between MLflow tracking servers (workspaces) regardless of the subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/mlflow/migrate-mlflow-objects

You can also post the question at: https://community.databricks.com/